# Should I use Node.js Greenlock-Express with cluster mode at the same time I'm using pm2 cluster mode?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, pm2, greenlock

I'm building an stateless Web application using Node.js, Express and pm2 for process management.
In production environments, I run one instance of the application for each core of the server CPU (thanks to pm2 cluster mode).

Recently I started to read about Greenlock-Express (for obtaining certificates automatically) and it also has a "cluster" property, which if I understand correctly it basically does the same thing as pm2 cluster mode.

Will there be any collisions or possible issues if I run both Greenlock-Express and pm2 in cluster mode? If they do, what's the best alternative to obtain automatically SSL certificates with Node.js in a Windows enviroment? And if they do not, is it optimal to use both of them in cluster mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM2 only implements partial cluster support.

See https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock-express.js/issues/26

I'd recommend just using [`serviceman`](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/serviceman) (cross-platform) or raw `systemd` (linux) or `Docker` (cloud deploys).

If you are going to use PM2, you use Greenlock Express with it the same way that you would use it with Ruby, Python, etc - as a separate executable, not as a "built-in" app.

PM2s default optimizations for node apps are already implemented in Greenlock Express, and since PM2 only has partial cluster support, there's not a way to tell PM2 to pass control to Greenlock Express, nor to have PM2 accept control from Greenlock Express.

Also: Only use `cluster` mode if you actually have multiple CPU cores otherwise you'll cause thread thrashing and slow down your process.